# How can i put in a limit a letter with undescore letter?

Tags: amsmath

[image]

well, i have to write the limit in latex, but i don't know why i can't write un underscore caracter in the limit argument.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\lim_{v\rightarrow v_{\varepsilon}}`?

Comment: i'll write something like that \lim_{V\to\V_varepsilon} \rho = \rho_A

Answer (score 2):

You get an underscore with `\_`, but I do not think it's an underscore (too high). I suspect an arrow together with the "circ", which might be an triangle arrow head. The arrow version makes more sense in mathematics. The limes is calculated, when variable *V* converges to *V<sub>ε</sub>*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \lim_{V\!\_ \circ V_\varepsilon} \quad\text{vs.}\quad
  \lim_{V\rightarrow V_\varepsilon}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That strange symbol is clearly an arrow; I've often seen it in hand writing in Italy.